Автоматическое обновление расширение chrome без Chrome Web Store
Есть расширение для Chroma, но постоянно стакиваемся с проблемой, что стоит добавить какой то функционал, то надо пререставить его на всех 80 пользователей.
В магазин опубликовать не можем. да и не хотим. Есть желание обновлять со своего сервера. Вопрос как?
Полистал статьи , но как понял сейчас это делать запретили, или не прав и есть возможно как это сделать?
Нашел только как это сделать для пользователей Linux.
